# "XX.sty not found" error happening for so many style files that worked well before

Tags: pdftex, lyx, pdf

When I try to export lyx file to pdf, I am seeing so many errors like this

```
LaTex Error: File `blindtext.sty' not found
```

Then I give up using this, so I delete "\usepackage{blindtext}" from preamble. Then another sty file is not found as well.

But these styles files worked well before. I don't know why they stopped working.

Is there any way that I can mass-install sty files that are commonly used? They are just small files so it won't matter if I install thousands of them.

Also, individually putting sty files onto so-called local directoy does not seem to work. Maybe it's because I can't see where is the so-called "local directory" where lyx references sty file is located.

Comment: You have an incomplete basic LaTeX distro,  or the files are there, but the path to the files is not searchable, or maybe you have a full and perfectly installed LaTeX distro, but you forget the LyX  menu Tools → Reconfigure.

Comment: @Fran   Tools->Reconfiture  does not solve the problem. I did it many times in no vain. How can I find any other solution?

Comment: With the details you have given about the problem, not much more can be said. As explained above then you have not installed all needed LaTeX packages or the installation is wrong, most probably  because you have not set the system to make searchable the directories of LaTeX (i.e., put some like `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` in the PATH) but the solution depends of your OS, which LaTeX is installed and how you installed LaTeX exactly.